# Updating Django model using selected collection of objects

Tags: python, django, model-view-controller, web-applications, model

I am learning `Django` and I refer `djangobook.com`.

I have a model like this:

```
class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    website = models.URLField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have populated some data (as described in the demo) and tried to update the value of a particular field of a record (as explained) and this works perfectly fine:

```
>>> publisher_list = Publisher.objects.all()
>>> p = publisher_list[0]
>>> p.name = u'Apress'
>>> p.save()
```

But when I try the below (which I assume is equivalent to the above), it does not work. The name is not updated in the database. What am I doing wrong here?

```
>>> publisher_list = Publisher.objects.all()
>>> publisher_list[0].name = 'Apress'
>>> publisher_list[0].save()
```

Reference: `http://djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter05/`

Thanks.

Comment: Please note that the Django Book you are referencing is becoming *seriously* out of date. Django just went to rev 1.4, which varies in many important ways (and by more than 3 years) from the Django 1.0 the book is about. The current docs & tutorials are *excellent*, so use those instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indexing is retrieving the model from the database multiple times. Bind the model to a name before mutating and saving it.

Answer (score 1):

According to [`QuerySet.__getitem__()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L166), retrieving by item, for example by `qs[0]`, is not cached and will hit DB for each accessing, **unless** the queryset has been evaluated and thus cache has been filled:

```
>>> qs = User.objects.all()[:10]
>>> qs[0] is qs[0] # Similar with your issue, you modified the attribute of the first and tried to save the latter.
False
>>> len(qs) # evaluate and fill cache
10
>>> qs[0] is qs[0]
True
```

So you could

- follow Ignacio's answer, or just `p = Publisher.objects.all()[0]`
- or, evaluate the queryset before indexing. Whether this could be easier depends on your code logic.